# How do I correctly pass information from a long-running thread to the UI thread in Android?

Tags: android, multithreading

My app has a chat feature. When my app first starts up, I spawn a listener thread to listen for incoming data:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static LinkedList<Message> chatList;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        chatList = new LinkedList<Message>();

        Handler listenerThreadHandler = new Handler();

        MyListener myListener = new MyListener(listenerThreadHandler, MainActivity.this);
        Thread listenerThread = new Thread(myListener);
        listenerThread.start();
    }
}
```

My chat feature is a Fragment/Tab within my main activity. It has your standard window for viewing the chat, plus an EditText and Button for sending chats:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/chat_window" android:orientation="vertical">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/received_chats"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll">
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/control_window" android orientation="horizontal">
        <EditText android:id="@+id/chat_entry_window" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/send_chat_button" android:text="Send" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

When I send a text, I add it to my main LinkedList.

```
    public class Chat extends Fragment {

    private View rootView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View rootView, Bundle, savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(rootView, savedInstanceState);
        displayChats();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        displayChats();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(){
        Button sendChatButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.send_chat_button);
        sendChatButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                EditText chatEntryWindow = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.chat_text_entry);
                // Add the chat to the LinkedList
                MainActivity.chatList.add(chatEntryWindow.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }

    public void dispalyChats(){
        final ArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(getActivity, R.layout.line_of_chat_text, MainActivity.chatList);
        final ListView list = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.received_chats);
        list.smoothScrollToPosition(list.getCount() - 1);
    }
}
```

I also add any incoming chats to the app in the listener

```
public class MyListener implements Runnable {
    Handler myHandler;
    Context myContext;
    public MyListener(Handler myHandler, Context myContext){
        this.myHandler = myHandler;
        this.myContext = myContext;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        listenForChats();
    }

    public listenForChats(){
        // here is where I want to add chats to my main list.
        MainActivity.chatList.add(received_chat);
    }
}
```

What I want to be able to do is to pass the text received by my ListenerThread back to the UI thread to be inserted into the LinkedList. I know I need to do this because I get this error every so often in my app:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>
> The content of the adapter has changed but listview did not receive a notification.
>
> Make sure the content of your adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.

I have used a Handler before, but I don't know if I am using it correctly here. In the past, I have passed in a layout element (e.g., TextView, ImageView, etc.) and have updated it with the handler.

In my listener thread, I changed

```
MainActivity.chatList.add(received_chat);
```

to

```
myHandler.post(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        MainActivity.chatList.add(received_chat);
    }
});
```

My chats are still getting added to the main LinkedList, but I don't know if it is any different from the way I originally did it or not. How do I know if I have successfully passed the data back to the UI thread?

So, how do I correctly pass data from my listener thread to the UI thread for adding to the LinkedList?

Comment: you need to update ui from the ui thread.

Comment: here's a blog post http://techtej.blogspot.in/2011/02/android-passing-data-between-main.html that can help

Comment: @DanielNugent I call listenForChats() from the run() method of my listener thread.

Comment: When you have a long running task, you shouldn't use a normal `Thread` especially when you pass in your `Activity`. What do you think will happen, if the user navigates away from your `Activity` and the `Activity` is killed by Android at some point? The `Thread` still has a reference to your `Activity`, but the `Activity` was destroyed. This will end up with a memoryleak.
You could look into `Loader`s that will run together with your `Activity` and when it's done, it will return the result to your `Activity` on the UI thread. See: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html

Comment: My thread runs as long as my application runs. Google's own documentation says to not use an AsyncTask for long running tasks. At that point, I was forced to use a "normal" thread.